# Jest is green even if Expected is not equal Received

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, redux-thunk

```
it('User is already present as a supplier', (done) => {
    const store = mockStore({}, [{ type: 'get_user', data: { } }]);
    return store.dispatch(userGetAction({ role: 'supplier' }, () => {})).then(() => {
      try {
        expect(store.getActions()[0].data.disabled).toEqual(true);
        expect(store.getActions()[0].data.errormessage).toEqual('User is already present as a assitantbuyer');
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      done();
    }).catch(() => {
      done();
    });
  });
```

Why it is passing and showing green status even it is Expected is not equal to Actual.

```
PASS  src/actions/user-get-action-assistant-buyer.test.jsx
  ● Console

    console.error node_modules/fbjs/lib/warning.js:33
    console.log src/actions/user-get-action-assistant-buyer.test.jsx:25
      { Error: expect(received).toEqual(expected)

      Expected value to equal:
        "User is already present"
      Received:
        "User is already present"
          at store.dispatch.then (/Users/prakashchandrabarnwal/Desktop/myProductInduct_CE_Admin/src/actions/user-get-action-assistant-buyer.test.jsx:23:57)
        matcherResult: 
         { actual: 'User is already present as a assitant buyer',
           expected: 'User is already present as a assitantbuyer',
           message: [Function],
           name: 'toEqual',
           pass: false } }
```

If i do not wrap expect inside try catch its silently going inside .catch()

thunk code returning UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:

```
const buyerAction = (data = {}, cb) => dispatch => axios({
  method: 'POST',
  url: `http://localhost:3001/api/manageUsers`,
  headers: {
    'x-access-token': authService.getAccessToken()
  },
  data
}).then(res => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if (res.status === 200 && res.data) {
    dispatch({ type: 'buyer_created', data: res.data.message });
    if (data.role === 'buyer') {
      axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: `http://localhost:3001/api/populateBuyerLookUp`,
        headers: {
          'x-access-token': authService.getAccessToken()
        },
        data
      })

.then((response) => {
            resolve(response);
          }).catch((err) => {
            reject(err);
          });
        }
        cb(res.data.message);
      } else {
        reject(res);
      }
    }))
      .catch(() => {
        console.log('error');
      });
```

(node:44182) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

Answer (score 2):

So, your `expect` fails with an error, you catch this error and just log it, in other words, you mute the error. After all, you call "done" just like there is no error. 
The code doing things just like you wrote: ignore and mute any errors. You have to remove all `catch` from your test

```
it('User is already present as a supplier', () => {
    const store = mockStore({}, [{ type: 'get_user', data: { } }]);
    return store
       .dispatch(userGetAction({ role: 'supplier' }, () => {}))
       .then(() => {
            expect(store.getActions()[0].data.disabled).toEqual(true);
            expect(store.getActions()[0].data.errormessage).toEqual('User is already present as a assitantbuyer');
        });
  });
```

You can return Promise from your test (There is no need to use `done`) and if promise fails, the whole test fails. that's all

UPD: regarding `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`, I think it could be linked with your request to the "populateBuyerLookUp", this request completely out of the flow. I tried to fix it, but it difficult to understand what you want to do exactly

```
    const buyerAction = (data = {}, cb) => dispatch => axios({
  method: 'POST',
  url: `http://localhost:3001/api/manageUsers`,
  headers: {
    'x-access-token': authService.getAccessToken()
  },
  data
})
  .then((res) => {
    dispatch({type: 'buyer_created', data: res.data.message});
    let promise;
    if (data.role === 'buyer') {
      promise = axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: `http://localhost:3001/api/populateBuyerLookUp`,
        headers: {
          'x-access-token': authService.getAccessToken()
        },
        data
      });
    }

    return Promise.resolve(promise).then(() => res.data.message);
  })
  .then((message) => {
    cb(message)
  }).catch(()=>{console.log("error")});
```

Comment: can you show me a example how to use done in this case?

Comment: can you please review thunk code, it is throwing UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning whenever I test negative scenarios.

Comment: @bikkybarnwal, I've updated the answer, please take a look